# Detecting when a user leaves (i.e. by closing their browser)

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Singleton service, `GameServer` which keeps track of guests to a particular page, a `Game.razor` page, and a Scoped service, `GameBridge`, between them.  `Gamebridge` is injected into `Game.razor`, and `GameServer` is injected into `Gamebridge`.

`GameServer` sends out a ping event, which is relayed by `GameBridge` to the page.  The page then calls a method in `Gamebridge`, which is relayed to `GameServer`, and sets a `LastSeen` DateTime to DateTime.Now for the user.

The idea was that if the user closes their browser, the Scoped service would be disposed, and the `GameServer` would no longer get update pings from the user, i.e. the user has timed out, and games can be forfeited, game rooms abandoned and so on.

**The problem** is that even if the browser is closed, `Game.razor` and `GameBridge` keep chugging along like everything's fine-- which I can see because the time value for the missing user keeps updating.  As of right now, I cannot detect the user disconnection even when they close the browser in blazor server side.

Comment: Blazor server? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59980882/how-can-i-get-the-event-while-page-close-in-blazor-server-side

Comment: Yes, blazor server.  That link looks like it's probably the right track.  I'll drink another cup of coffee and see if I can get it working tonight.  (It's midnight here, but I'm pretty keen to get this done)

Comment: @Steve Greene, thank you very much!  With a little tinkering, I was able to isolate the circuit for several windows on a couple browsers.  I'm quite confident I can move forward, and I can drop all the events and most of the method calls.  I'm a little worried, though-- why are `GameBridge` and `Game.razor` still instantiated?  Do I need to dispose of all event subscriptions etc. etc. ?

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 I have done this before by using Signalr and overriding ondisconnect in the hub. However this was in WASM but the principal is the same.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I didn't find many examples about this, and the MSDN docs, which are usually pretty good, weren't helpful.  Hopefully if I have time later, I can post a bare-bones user server here.

Answer (score 1):

My solution hooks into the browser window `beforeunload` event, and uses a Guid to track SPA sessions.

This is my demo system which you an adapt to fit your code.

Add a Singleton Service and register it.

```
using System;

namespace Blazor.App.Services
{
    public class SessionTrackerService
    {
        // Session List, blah, blah, ..

        public void NotifyNewSession(Guid ID)
        {
            //  Do whatever you want
            Debug.WriteLine($"Session {ID} Registered");
        }

        public void NotifySessionClosed(Guid ID)
        {
            var x = 0;
            Debug.WriteLine($"Session {ID} Closed");
            // Do re-registering
        }
    }
}
```

**site.js** registered in base page.

```
window.blazor_setExitEvent = function (dotNetHelper) {
    blazor_dotNetHelper = dotNetHelper;
        window.addEventListener("beforeunload", blazor_SetSPAClosed);
}

var blazor_dotNetHelper;

window.blazor_SetSPAClosed = function() {
    blazor_dotNetHelper.invokeMethodAsync('SPASessionClosed')
    blazor_dotNetHelper.dispose();
}
```

Add some code to `App.razor`.  Cascade the `SessionID` if you need to use it elsewhere.  Call `window.blazor_setExitEvent` to set the window `beforeunload` event and pass it a reference to `App`.

```
<CascadingValue Name="SessionID" Value="this.ID">
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly" PreferExactMatches="@true">
        .....
    </Router>
</CascadingValue>

@code {
    [Inject] private IJSRuntime _js { get; set; }
    [Inject] private SessionTrackerService sessionTrackerService { get; set; }
    public Guid ID { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    protected async override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            sessionTrackerService.NotifyNewSession(ID);
            var dotNetReference = DotNetObjectReference.Create(this);
            await _js.InvokeVoidAsync("window.blazor_setExitEvent", dotNetReference);
        }
    }

    [JSInvokable("SPASessionClosed")]
    public void SPASessionClosed()
    {
        sessionTrackerService.NotifySessionClosed(ID);
    }
```

I tested in on Edge, Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: That's a nice-looking solution, but what happens if someone alt-F4?  I'm trying to implement a game server that will be used by children, and they're pretty crafty that way. 
 I've got the circuit system working fine-- been programming too much to share it, and not sure it isn't overkill.  I have an auxiliary question about that-- I found that if I implement CircuitHelper as a singleton, it shows ALL circuits, whereas scoped just gives own circuit.  I'd like to have BOTH implementations-- any ideas about that?

Comment: @Bennyboy1973.  Have you tested this?  Alt-F4 triggers the event in the same way that closing the tab or Browser does.  I've just tested it to be sure.

Comment: No I haven't tested it, as I already had CircuitHandler working by the time I read your answer.  I was just guessing that if you kill the browser, JavaScript will immediately stop functioning.